# Can't log value from parent for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, console.log

**JS Code**

```
function generate(rectWidth, rectHeight, amount) {

// holds size
let size = {
    width: [],
    height: []
};

// holds colors
let colors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    // generate size
    var width = Math.floor((Math.random() * rectWidth) + 1);
    var height = Math.floor((Math.random() * rectHeight) + 1);

    var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
    var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
    var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);

    // add size to object
    size.width.push(width);
    size.height.push(height);
    colors.push(`rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`);
}

return {
    size: size,
    colors: colors
};

};

let properties = generate(50, 50, 10);

for (let width = 0; width < properties.size.width.length; width++) {
        for (let height = 0; height < properties.size.height; height++) {
            for (let color = 0; color < properties.colors.length; color++) {

                console.log(properties.size.width[width]);

            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

So my problem is that in my code I'm trying to `console.log(properties.size.width[width]);`, but its not logging, and I'm not getting error messages.

**What I want to happen**

I want my code to `console.log()` the values of `properties.size.width`

**What I've tried**

1. I have tried using `var` instead of `let` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (let height = 0; height < properties.size.height; height++)` should be

```
for (let height = 0; height < properties.size.height.length; height++)
```

```js
function generate(rectWidth, rectHeight, amount) {

// holds size
let size = {
    width: [],
    height: []
};

// holds colors
let colors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    // generate size
    var width = Math.floor((Math.random() * rectWidth) + 1);
    var height = Math.floor((Math.random() * rectHeight) + 1);

    var r = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
    var g = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);
    var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1);

    // add size to object
    size.width.push(width);
    size.height.push(height);
    colors.push(`rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`);
}

return {
    size: size,
    colors: colors
};

};

let properties = generate(50, 50, 10);

for (let width = 0; width < properties.size.width.length; width++) {
        for (let height = 0; height < properties.size.height.length; height++) {
            for (let color = 0; color < properties.colors.length; color++) {

                console.log(properties.size.width[width]);

            }
        }
    }
```